What is the default button background color in MS Access?
I have a continuous form where I want buttons to be selectively enabled or disabled at the individual record level, which as far as I know is impossible. So my workaround is to create textboxes that look like buttons and use conditional formatting to make them look enabled or disabled.
But where I'm stuck is I can't find the color codes to match the default Access buttons (I probably need color codes for grayed-out text as well, come to think of it).
I tried using the default BackColor of a standard button, and I tried the SystemButtonFace color, but neither of them are anywhere near the actual button color.

I changed my answer after @Zaider's comment.

In an .mdb you can't change the Background color of a Button in Access. But there is a workaround: Use a Label instead. It also has a Click event and if you set its Special Effect to Raised it looks like a Button.
And you can make it move when it is clicked by adding these event handlers:
Private Sub MyLabel_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Label5.SpecialEffect = 2 'Sunken
End Sub

Private Sub MyLabel_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Label5.SpecialEffect = 1 'Raised
End Sub

See: Label.SpecialEffect property (Access)

In an .accdb you can change the Background color if you set the UseTheme property to Yes. (The UseTheme property does not exist in .mdbs.)



You can change the Background color of a button in Access: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.commandbutton.backcolor]

I'm not trying to change the background color of a button, I'm trying to match it. Unfortunately I have to use textboxes because conditional formatting doesn't apply to labels.

@Zaider, link does not work.

Working link: CommandButton.BackColor property (Access). Despite what the link says, setting the BG color does not work for me.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes are you using a .mdb or .accdb file?  It also seems to require the UseTheme Property set to Yes.

@Zaider, good point. I updated my answer accordingly.

Never mind, I figured it out. I just used a color picker. It's not uniform across the button, but I ended up going with dee6fa.

Just a note, button colors are probably more dependent on Windows version and -design settings than on Access settings. If your application is used on multiple computers with individual user settings, this may be a minor issue.
